# C++ OpenCV Eliminate smaller Contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing a OpenCV project.

I am currently working on detecting contours of particular ROI (Regoin Of Interest). What I want to achieve is to eliminate all the smaller contours in other words I do not want these smaller contours to be drown at all.

So Far if I have coded this algorithm to do this job:

CODE:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(mBlur, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    //Contours Vectors
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect (contours.size());
    vector<Point2f> ContArea(contours.size());
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( range_out.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    //Detecting Contours
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     {  

        ContArea.clear();
        ContArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x, boundRect[i].y));
        ContArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x + boundRect[i].width, boundRect[i].y));
        ContArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x + boundRect[i].width, boundRect[i].y + boundRect[i].height));
        ContArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x, boundRect[i].y + boundRect[i].height));

        double area = contourArea(ContArea);

        if(area > 2000)
        {
           approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
           boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]));


           cout<<"The area of Contour: "<<i<< " is: " <<area<<endl;

        }
     }



    /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects


   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {

        Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255);
        drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
        fillPoly(drawing, contours, Scalar(255,0,0));

    }
```

The problem here is that it looks like the if(area > 2000) statement is not executed even dough i know some of areas present in image are way bigger than this.

I have been trying a lot of different solutions but this looks to be the most appropriate one to me.

THE KEY QUESTIONS:

Is it Possible to achieve what I want with the given code....?
If so can anyone see where I am going wrong with this
Else Could someone suggest some kind of solution or a good online source....?

Comment: Ok a little update I removed the if statement and no i can see that for each contour detected the area is 0 therefore it has to be something to do with my area calculations

Comment: The `boundRect` is empty. You only set it's capacity, with the `contours.size()`, so I think they are always empty `Rect`. And one more thing, you want remove small contours or small ROIs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove based on the size of ROIs, you can do as follow (based on the example of [bounding box of opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)):

```
vector< vector< Point > > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector< Rect > boundRect (contours.size() );
vector< Point2f > centeres ( contours.size() );
vector< float > radiuses ( contours.size() );

// finding the approximate rectangle and circle of contours
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
  {
    approxPolyDP( Mat ( contours[i] ), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat ( contours_poly[i] ) );
    minEnclosingCircle( ( Mat ) contours_poly[i], centeres[i], radiuses[i] );
  }
```

The above code snippet gives you the approximate rectangles of contours (`boundRect`), and approximate circles (`centers`, `radiuses`). After this you must be able to call `contourArea();` and if it's smaller than certain threshold, you can eliminate it.

---

If you just want to remove contours that are smaller certain length, you can calculate it's length, [look at the answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11132942/2194309), and it seems you can use `arcLength()` function. I think something like this: `double perimeter = arcLength ( Mat ( contours[i] ), true );`.